# <img/> tag width and height not correct when getting it from $('img).width()/height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am currently trying to get RGB data for a texture image, while displaying a preview of the texture to the user.

The user drops an image file into the form, and it should show the preview of the image, while drawing the image to an canvas to get the RGB values for each pixel:

```
handleTextureImageDrop = (e) ->
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()
  if e.dataTransfer.files.length >= 1
    file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]
  if file
    reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (loadEvent) ->
      img = $ '<img/>'
      img.attr
        src: loadEvent.target.result
      $(e.target).html img
    reader.onloadend = (loadendEvent) ->
      img = $(e.target).children 'img'
      width = img.width()
      height = img.height()
      canvas = $ '<canvas/>', 
        width: width
        height: height
      $('#wrapper').append canvas
      context = $('canvas').get(0).getContext '2d'
      context.drawImage img.get(0), 0, 0
      rgb = (for x in [0...width]
               for y in [0...height]
                 context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data)
      canvas.remove()
      TEXTURE_FILES.push 
        image: file.name
        rgb: rgb
    reader.readAsDataURL file
```

As it stands it works about 50% of the time, but the rest of the time `width` and `height` are set to `0`, so the iteration across the pixel data never happens.

This would suggest to me that there is some sort of race condition happening where the image hasn't loaded into the `<img/>` tag yet.

Is that what is happening? Or am I missing something silly and obvious?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get correct width and height only after the image has been loaded. Usually `$(img).load` is used for this.

```
$(img).load(function(e){
     var w = $(img).width();
     var h = $(img).height();
});
$(img).attr("src", "http://....");
```

I am not familiar with coffeescript, so I am not able to understand whether you are doing this in your current code. If not please try it.

Comment: The CoffeeScript version would look something [like this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24(img).load%20(e)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20w%20%3D%20%24(img).width()%0A%20%20%20%20h%20%3D%20%24(img).height()%0A). I think you're right about the "`<img>` not loaded yet" problem in any case.